# Creating a generic PowerBI model to deploy and populate at multiple client sites

Tags: ssis, ssas, powerbi

I have an industry-specific (think: real estate, construction) generic model that I'd like to build to use as a starting point for consulting with each client.  Presumably this model is also going to require some customization for each client, which for now I'm assuming will not be merged back into the original base model.  Each client is going to have their version of the data stored in a different way (ERP, SQL, Excel, CSV, etc)

My question is related to how & where I should build this model, and how to populate it.  Should the model be built in PowerBI desktop, and then data loaded using PowerQuery append queries?  Or, should the model be built in SQL Server, and more traditional ETL scripts first populate that, and then *that* is imported into PowerBI?

Answer (score 2):

The choice between doing your ETL using Power BI Desktop, or doing your ETL in SQL Server and then importing the final data into Power BI Desktop comes down to 3 factors:

1. **Portability**. Using Power BI Desktop for your ETL means that your entire solution is in Power BI Desktop - you don't need any other tools to deploy your solution. If you can't guarantee that each client has the same version of SQL Server and the same ETL tools, then I would not recommend building dependencies on such external tools. *Exception: If your clients will be the ones building the ETL, then you will likely want to keep your client-written ETLs out of your Power BI Desktop solution - and you will likely not care about what database/ETL solution they use, as long as the final result meets your specifications*
2. **Processing Power** (or how intensive the ETL is). If the ETL is highly intensive and needs all the power of a server to run, then a SQL Server/traditional ETL may be better. Any ETL in Power BI Desktop necessarily runs where Power BI Desktop is installed. If that's a lower-spec computer, then an intensive ETL is going to be much slower than when using a traditional server-based ETL tool.
3. **Maintainability**. If you're going to be maintaining the ETL going forwards, then sticking with a tool you know really well (like Power Query) is a better plan than using a different external ETL tool for each client. However, if your clients are going to be maintaining the ETL, then they may prefer the ETL to be built in the same way as, and act like, other ETLs they maintain.

I imagine, given that you're working with multiple clients, that portability trumps almost everything else. The less you need from your clients, the better.

What *doesn't* matter in this decision is the size of your data, since all the data will be imported into Power BI Desktop no matter what (as you specified in your question).

If you *were* to go the path of an external database/ETL solution, then a natural next step would be to explore Direct Query mode or a live connection to a cube (rather than importing the data). The pros & cons of this would be another factor to consider in your decision. However, since you're building solutions for clients, this is likely another tool you wouldn't want to have a dependency on anyway.

Overall, for your situation (building solutions for clients), I would recommend Power BI Desktop.

For other people reading this who are building in-house solutions, the recommendation is not necessarily the same (and would depend on the circumstances that apply to them).

Comment: One additional consideration I didn't cover is whether Power BI Desktop and/or the external ETL tool can do everything required to transform the client's data. If you run into something the tool can't do, then naturally the other tool might be a better choice. I didn't mention this because (a) I imagine every client system is different anyway, and (b) where there's a will, there's a way. If you opt for Power BI, then run into something it can't do (e.g. a source system you can't query), you can always use another tool to get over that hurdle (e.g. have the client stage the data for you).